# How to determine the date and app version of a UWP app when it was first downloaded from the Windows Store?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I have a basic Windows 10 UWP app:

- Version 1.0 was a paid app
- In version 2.0 I added a free trial
- In version 3.0 I'd like to switch to "free with In-App purchases".

I'd like to grandfather all existing users that downloaded version 1.0 or 2.0 into the old feature set, whereas new users that download v3.0 for the first time should be presented with the In-App purchase choices.

For that I need to be able to determine the initial app version (or date) at which the app was initially bought/downloaded from the Windows Store each time my app starts so that I know which feature set to offer.

I discovered `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp`, but the docs say that this namespace should not be used anymore. How can I tell at which app version the user initially bought the app?

Answer (score 1):

[StoreCollectionData.AcquiredDate Property (Windows.Services.Store)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecollectiondata.acquireddate) will tell you when the app was acquired. Since you know when the updates were published, you can infer by the acquired date which version they purchased.

```cs
public static async Task<StoreProductQueryResult> GetAppGameProduct(string ProductId)
{
    string[] productKinds = { "Application", "Game" };

    List<String> filterList = new List<string>(productKinds);
    List<String> idsList = new List<string>();
    idsList.Add(ProductId);
    if (_products == null)
    {
        _products = await _storeContext.GetStoreProductsAsync(filterList, idsList);
    }
    return _products;
}

private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var all = await GetAppGameProduct("<Product Id - See App Identity").ConfigureAwait(true);
    foreach (var product in all.Products)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<StoreSku> skus = (product.Value as StoreProduct).Skus;

        for (int i = 0; i < skus.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"{0} {1}", "Title: ", skus[i].Title);
            Debug.WriteLine(@"{0} {1}", "IsTrial: ", skus[i].IsTrial);
            if (skus[i].CollectionData != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"{0} {1}", "CollectionData.AcquiredDate: ", skus[i].CollectionData.AcquiredDate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to grandfather all existing users that downloaded version 1.0 or 2.0 into the old feature set, whereas new users that download v3.0 for the first time should be presented with the In-App purchase choices.

For now, there's no built-in APIs for you to do it. You would have to do judgement in your code by yourself.

For example, you could use LocalSettings to make a flag in your previous project(v1, v2) code like the following:

```cs
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package package = Package.Current;
PackageId packageId = package.Id;
PackageVersion version = packageId.Version;
if (version.Major < 3)
{
     ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["IsForPreviousVersion"] = true;
}
```

Then, you could publish a version 2.x.x.x to the store for the existing users, let them update their installed app. Once they open your app, your code will work and the flag will be in the LocalSettings. The LocalSettings will not be cleared when they update to the next app version. But, if the users have not open your app when they updated your app, the flag will not be created in the LocalSettings. So, you need to notify the users to open your app when they update to this 2.x.x.x version.

After that, you could publish your v3.0 to the store and do judgement in your code like the following:

```cs
var IsForPreviousVersion = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["IsForPreviousVersion"];
if (IsForPreviousVersion != null)
{
    // is for previous version users
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see one potential problem: what if the user switches to a different computer and tries to download v3 there? There won't be any LocalSettings. Same problem occurs if the user reinstalls their computer (and hence loses LocalSettings). I could use roaming data, but even that is not kept indefinitely...

Comment: @xavier-xie-msft Would you consider adding an API to StoreLicense to determine the original app version when the app was first acquired by the user?

Comment: @Mark You could submit a 'Feature Request'  on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/) . The relevant team would think about it.